# Sequence contains no Elements at System.Linq.Enumerable.Single[Tsource](IEnumerable'1 source)

Tags: c#, openxml

I am running some test and using OpenXML now I want to get the data into an Array and save to their respective content controls. I tried and I am getting this execption

```
Sequence contains no Elements at System.Linq.Enumerable.Single[Tsource](IEnumerable'1 source)
```

With this source code :

```
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace PopulateContentsOpenXml
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string myfile = @"C:\Users\*****\Desktop\DTestDoc.docx";
            string[] writeDocData = new string[] {FirstName.Text,FileNumber.Text,IDNumber.Text,LastName.Text };
            WriteDataToContentControl(myfile, writeDocData);
        }

        private void WriteDataToContentControl(string filename,string[]data)
        {
            try
            {
                using (WordprocessingDocument doc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(filename, true))
                {
                    MainDocumentPart mainPart = doc.MainDocumentPart;
                    foreach (string text in data) 
                    {
                        SdtElement text_block = mainPart.Document.Body.Descendants<SdtElement>().Where(r => r.SdtProperties.GetFirstChild<Tag>().Val == text).Single();
                        Text to = text_block.Descendants<Text>().Single();
                        to.Text = text;
                        mainPart.Document.Save();
                        MessageBox.Show("Ok i am fine now!");
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error: " + ex.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And i am getting the Exception on line 39 which is this line

```
SdtElement text_block = mainPart.Document.Body.Descendants<SdtElement>().Where(r => r.SdtProperties.GetFirstChild<Tag>().Val == text).Single();
```

**Edits**
Doing this

```
        SdtElement text_block = mainPart.Document.Body.Descendants<SdtElement>().Where(r => r.SdtProperties.GetFirstChild<Tag>().Val == text).SingleOrDefault();

        Text to = text_block.Descendants<Text>().Single();
```

I am having Object not set to instance of an object. now having checked, it says text_block is null

Why is this so?

Comment: What's the result of?? mainPart.Document.Body.Descendants<SdtElement>().Where(r => r.SdtProperties.GetFirstChild<Tag>().Val == text);

Comment: Nothing it did not give any result, just fired that exception in a messagebox

Comment: Try and break this statement and check the result of each part. e.g. result of .... mainPart.Document.Body.Descendants<SdtElement>() then further on.

Comment: @AzharKhorasany, Please see Edits

Comment: What have you edited? I can't see any edit on your OP?

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of Linq extension methods that will throw an exception in case the sequence (e.g., `IEnumerable<T>`) is empty or does not fulfill the assertion you are making by calling that method.

`Single<TSource>()` will throw an exception if your sequence does not contain **exactly one** element. Thus, it throws an exception if the sequence is empty or contains more than one element. This is what happened to you. There is no  `SdtElement` with that given tag value.

`First<TSource>()` and `Last<TSource>()` will also throw an exception if the sequence is empty. They expect **at least one** element in the sequence.

If you can't guarantee that your sequence is non-empty, meaning it will contain exactly or at least one `SdtElement`, you should use `SingleOrDefault<TSource>()` or potentially `FirstOrDefault<TSource>()`.

`SingleOrDefault<TSource>()` will not throw if the sequence is empty, but it will throw if it contains more than one element. Thus, it expects **at most one** element.

`FirstOrDefault<TSource>()` will not throw in any case. It will return `null` if the sequence of `SdtElement` instances is empty. If it is not empty, it will return the first `SdtElement`, ignoring the others. Thus, it expects **zero or more** elements.

Comment: SingleOrDefault() and FirstOrDefault() fires this error, object not set to an instance of an Object

Comment: Your sequence does not contain any elements, which is why `Single()` threw an exception. In this case, `SingleOrDefault()` and `FirstOrDefault()` both return `null`. Thus, whenever you are using `SingleOrDefault()` or `FirstOrDefault()` (or anything else that can return `null`), you should check for `null` and then not try to get the descendants of `null`.

Comment: Please accept and upvote if this answered your question.

Comment: Error is still there Sir. Still doing some research on how it can be resolved

Comment: @Ukrainian, your question was about why the `Single()` method throws an exception and, after trying `SingleOrDefault()`, you added that you were "having Object not set to instance of an object. now having checked, it says text_block is null". I answered both questions. Your question does not talk about any other error or root cause, for which you also did not provide any details. If you want us to be able to help you, you need to provide enough context and ideally a minimal, reproducible example.